# Do power MOSFETs have significant disadvantages over normal MOSFETs?

Tags: voltage, power, transistors, current, mosfet

I have noticed that many power MOSFETs are cheaper, have a much greater \$I_{D}\$ and \$V_{DS}\$, and have comparable \$R_{DS(on)}\$ and \$V_{GS(th)}\$ values to normal MOSFETs amongst other advantages (shorter \$t_{d(on)}\$ times, etc.) without any apparent disadvantages. For example, the [IPS105N03L G](http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/1090/0900766b81090909.pdf) is cheaper and (apart from having a lower \$V_{DS}\$) appears to be better than the [2N7000](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/2N/2N7000.pdf) in every possible way.

### IPS105N03L G

- \$I_{D}\$ = 35A
- \$V_{DS}\$ = 30V
- \$V_{GS}\$ = \$\pm\$20V
- \$R_{DS(on)}\$ = 15.5mΩ (max)
- \$t_{d(on)}\$ = 3.7ns
- \$t_{d(off)}\$ = 14ns
- \$V_{GS(th)}\$ = 1 - 2.2V

### 2N7000

- \$I_{D}\$ = 0.2A
- \$V_{DS}\$ = 60V
- \$V_{GS}\$ = \$\pm\$20V
- \$R_{DS(on)}\$ = 5Ω (max)
- \$t_{d(on)}\$ = 10ns
- \$t_{d(off)}\$ = 10ns
- \$V_{GS(th)}\$ = 0.8 - 3V

What am I missing here? Do power MOSFETs have any significant disadvantages as such, or are they suitable for general purpose use?

Comment: I think your missing a crucial detail. The 2N7000 is from the mid 1990's while the IPS105N03L G is dated 2010. This is a major generation gap so construction techniques and purity of materials play a large part in performance.

Comment: @Sparky while they are different ages, I'm sure you could pick 1990s parts with specs much closer to the IPS105. The ubiquitous IRF540 for example has been around for a while (the 1991 edition of "Art of Electronics)  and its 20A, 0.077 ohm ratings are much closer than the 2N7000.

Comment: @BrianDrummond. I agree with your statement in that some lines were already high performance while others did not change, but are still on the market. But many improvements have been made to mosfets over the years, such as HEXFETS, and I did not want the generation gap left out of the overall picture.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Of course, they have some disadvantages, and in some applications, they are totally unsuitable. Both types of mosfets offer some compromises on different aspects.

First: regarding the price, I don't know where you got the estimations, but they're inaccurate. Mouser offers 2N7002 starting from about 0.12€, whereas IPS105N03L is about 0.68€. So it's not exactly cheaper. Maybe you were looking for a specific packaging of 2N7002 (TO-220, perhaps), which made the price much higher, but 2N7002 is actually one of the cheapest mosfet available.

Now, even without looking at the price, there are parameters other than I<sub>D</sub>, V<sub>DS</sub> and R<sub>DS(on)</sub> that characterizes a mosfet. For example:

- V<sub>GS(th)</sub>, the gate threshold voltage. For power mosfets, it is usually higher than small mosfets. Small mosfets can be driven directly with a 3.3V voltage, which is convenient. This is not always the case for power mosfets. However, for the two mosfets you compare, there is no significant difference.
- The gate charge. Here, for IPS105N03L, we have 14nC of total gate charge, whereas for 2N7002, it is less than 1nC. Basically, this means that, when the mosfet changes state, the power mosfet will require a *lot* of current through its gate to overcome the miller effect. So you need big drivers to make it switch fast. However, the 2N7002 can be very easily driven, and even a simple MCU output pin can drive it as fast as you want. So it makes your design much simpler. This is where small mosfets shine.

Comment: Surprisingly enough, RS components are selling the IPS for £0.14 with free shipping... Just to aid my understanding, do you reckon a microcontroller could operate a power MOSFET like the IPS directly (with sufficient protection, of course)?

Comment: Well, RS has strange prices sometimes. Cheap stuff becomes expensive, and a few expensive stuff become cheap. Anyway, regarding the operation of IPS with a MCU, the *Vgs(th)* allows it, but not for high currents. Look at page 5 of datasheet, the diagram on the top-left corner: *Id* vs *Vds*. With a 3.2 gate voltage, you can go up to ~10 amps, it seems. Be careful, these are typ. values, so you may want to derate. Also, this is possible only for applications where you don't switch often, because of the gate charge thing (high freq switching will require a driver).

Comment: Actually, how many amps do you want to switch and what will be the gate voltage ? 5 or 3.3V?

Comment: Well, I was thinking of switching around 1A (max) with a 5V gate voltage

Comment: Then, you're more than fine. With 5V, you can switch everything you want. Put a resistor between the MCU pin and the FET gate (something like 1k), so you don't overload the pin ratings, and just know that you won't be able to switch very fast (if you really need to know the switching time in these conditions, or the current through the gate, you can eventually make a quick simulation with the mosfet SPICE model).

Answer (score 3):

Those two are hardly comparable. The IPS part is about 10mm x 6mm and can dissipate 38 watts, input capacitance 1100pF typical, the 2N7 part is SOT-23, dissipating a fraction of a watt, with 20pF typical input cap.

Lower power parts always seem to be over-priced in hobby quantities, as the package, carrying stock, shipping etc tend to go more like per item rather than per current carrying capacity.

If you want to drive an array of 200mA loads, then the 2N7000s would be adequate, smaller and cheaper than the IPS parts.

If you only wanted to keep one part in your personal stock, then the larger one would be more flexible.

The IPS part is a much more recent design, using a smaller, cheaper process than the older 2N7000, so you are getting greatly increased performance, current, RDSon etc for 'free'.

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with the concept of input capacitance. How exactly does that affect performance and/or use?

Comment: see dim's answer on gate charge. Roughly charge = voltage*capacitance. A big gate charge means you have to drive a lot of current for a long time to switch it on. While the FET is switching, it's dissipating big time, so power FETs in SMPSs need drivers of several amps to slam the gates up and down and constrain the losses. It's a but easier with low charge FETs like 2N7000, but of course that can't do the current.

Answer (score 1):

Did you happen to compare cost? You can get BSS138 or 2N7002 for around $US 0.015 (in high volume). The BSS138 can be used in 3.3V CMOS logic circuits. There are versions of them available with very low gate leakage current, so they can be very useful for certain types of circuits in battery powered devices.

Usually power mosfets (ans some versions of above mentioned devices, too) have Zener diode protection built-in on the gate. This causes them to have very high leakage currents at the gate. Sometimes that is OK, and sometimes it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a power MOSFET where a small signal device would suffice, there is a price to pay in dollars, size, capacitance which could muck up high speed circuitry. And less stability when biasing the devices up in analog mode. Most of the time there will not be a performance penalty.